# MyISAM or InnoDB, for safety of data, which should I choose?

Tags: mysql, storage-engines

[MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) or [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB), for safety of data, which should I choose?

Comment: Y'know, I think the general idea is to put a summary of the question in the title, then flesh it out a bit in the body :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb.html) has better respect of constraints, data integrity and reliability. It supports foreign key constraints and transactions for instance... The documentation [compares transaction and nontransation engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-compare-transactions.html).

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB is a safer ACID compliant engine with some integrity features that MyISAM lacks.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Clearly, if you are concerned with de safety of your data I would use InnoDB. Would you use an engine that does not support transactions?

MyISAM is used for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

See, developer and site lard are expecting only safety, but users are expecting fast retrieval.

Only, in [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB) there is no fulltext support, so we manage in that situtaion.

Is there alternate constraints there, or is there any tips?

Example,

I have postcode file in my table,

I have around 100000 postcodes,

I have autocomplete for postcode, in this situtaion, if I use the MyISAM, I make the filed 
as fulltext, so my user will not experience a performance issue.

So is there any idea for this creteria?

Basically I am not a database engineer, I am a developer.